# how to display image from database to razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

so i have images in my database and i want to show them in my view,**this is my model:**

```
public class SocialNetworkModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string titlePost { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string descriptionPost { get; set; }

    public byte[] picturePost { get; set; }
 }
```

**this is my view :**

```
foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr id="row-@item.cinOw">
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.titlePost)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.descriptionPost)
    </td>
    <td>
        //here i want to put my image
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

so please if someone has any idea i will be very grateful.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149430/displaying-image-from-db-in-razor-mvc3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create action in your controller as below

```
public FileContentResult displayImage(int productId) {
    SocialNetwork item = //Get your object
    if (item!= null) {
        return File(item.picturePost, "image Mime Type");
    } else {
    return null;
 }
```

}

And show this returned file in the view.

Comment: oh sorry I didn't see the comment above. That has the solution.